# R:Keeping original ordering of matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix whose column names I switch around, but, when I do so, the columns reorder themselves. For example:
`BGASBK BTICFR`
becomes
`CFRBTI SBKBGA` (because I have switched the first three letters and the last 3 letters around)
I would, however, like for the new ordering to be the same as the original ordering i.e.
`SBKBGA CFRBTI`
In reality there are more than columns though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Which language is this in and what code do you have for this?

Comment: Its in R, thanks, just changed the title. The code I have so far is as follows:  `m[rownames(m) %in% gsub("(...)(...)","\\2\\1", rowsToSwitch, 8] = 
    1/m[rowsToSwitch,4]`, where m is the matrix containing the rownames that I wish to switch around, and rowsToSwitch are those rows within the m matrix which I actually want to interact with. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to store the original order in a column and use it to reorder your final result? Something like this :

```
A <- data.frame(a=c("BGASBK","BTICFR"),
           b=c("SBKBGA","CFRBTI"))
 ## I store the order of the column a to be used later
 A$ord <- order(A$a) ## here you can use many columns order(col1,col2,..)
```

Now if I have `B <- A[order(A$b),]` sotred by b , I can reorder it using ord column:

```
B[order(B$ord),]
```